# What is the default type for an attribute in an xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing an xml schema (xsd). What's the difference between the following? Is there any difference?

```
<xs:attribute name="Key" type="xs:string" />
```

and

```
<xs:attribute name="Key"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the default type is `xs:anySimpleType` rather than `xs:string`. From a validation perspective there's no difference, but `xs:anySimpleType` allows subtyping in a derived type as (say) `xs:integer`, whereas `xs:string` doesn't.